# Upgrading from Flink 1.3.2 to 1.4.0 hadoop FileSystem and Path issues

Tags: apache-flink, avro, parquet, flink-streaming

I recently tried upgrading from Flink 1.3.2 to 1.4.0 and I'm having some issues with not being able to import `org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}` anymore. The issue is occurring in two places:

ParquetWriter:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.Writer
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName

class AvroWriter[T <: GenericRecord]() extends Writer[T] {

  @transient private var writer: ParquetWriter[T] = _
  @transient private var schema: Schema = _

  override def write(element: T): Unit = {
    schema = element.getSchema
    writer.write(element)
  }

  override def duplicate(): AvroWriter[T] = new AvroWriter[T]()

  override def close(): Unit = writer.close()

  override def getPos: Long = writer.getDataSize

  override def flush(): Long = writer.getDataSize

  override def open(fs: FileSystem, path: Path): Unit = {
    writer = AvroParquetWriter.builder[T](path)
      .withSchema(schema)
      .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
      .build()
  }

}
```

CustomBucketer:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.Bucketer
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.Clock
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import java.io.ObjectInputStream
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class RecordFieldBucketer[T <: GenericRecord: ClassTag](dateField: String = null, dateFieldFormat: String = null, bucketOrder: Seq[String]) extends Bucketer[T] {

  @transient var dateFormatter: SimpleDateFormat = _

  private def readObject(in: ObjectInputStream): Unit = {
    in.defaultReadObject()
    if (dateField != null && dateFieldFormat != null) {
      dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFieldFormat)
    }
  }

  override def getBucketPath(clock: Clock, basePath: Path, element: T): Path = {
    val partitions = bucketOrder.map(field => {
      if (field == dateField) {
        field + "=" + dateFormatter.format(new Date(element.get(field).asInstanceOf[Long]))
      } else {
        field + "=" + element.get(field)
      }
    }).mkString("/")
    new Path(basePath + "/" + partitions)
  }

}
```

I noticed that Flink now has:

```
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
```

But new `Path` doesn't appear to work with the `AvroParquetWriter` or the `getBucketPath` method. I know there have been some changes with Flink's FileSystem and Hadoop dependencies and I'm just not sure what I need to import to makes my code work again.

Do I even need to to use the Hadoop dependencies or are there now different ways of writing and bucketing Parquet files to s3?

build.sbt:

```
val flinkVersion = "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.10" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-filesystem" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-metrics-core" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-metrics-graphite" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.0.1",
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.7.7",
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-hadoop" % "1.8.1",
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % "1.8.1",
  "io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "3.2.2",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.2"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary `org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}` classes are found in the [hadoop-commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common) project.

Answer (score 1):

Building a "Hadoop-Free-Flink" was one major feature of the 1.4 release.
All you have to do is to include the hadoop dependencies to your classpath or quoting the [changelogs](https://flink.apache.org/news/2017/12/12/release-1.4.0.html#hadoop-free-flink-1):

> ... This also means that in cases where you used connectors to HDFS, such as the BucketingSink or RollingSink, you now have to ensure that you either use a Flink distribution with bundled Hadoop dependencies or make sure to include Hadoop dependencies when building a jar file for your application.

Comment: Ok makes sense I'll try to track down the dependencies I need to include-- unless you know offhand. What I'm also wondering is if I even need to include the dependencies to write parquet to s3 or are there other ways of doing that now in Flink 1.4?